# How to write custom data into a cursor which is out parameter of an Oracle procedure

Tags: node.js, oracle, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

I'm doing an update operation in for loop if update got failed I need to send back the ids for which update has failed.

This is my stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  ROLESUPDATING(useResultIn IN ROLE_ARRAY,Output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. useResultIn.count
  LOOP
  BEGIN
  UPDATE AUTHUSERS SET FIRSTNAME = useResultIn(i).role  where USERID = useResultIn(i).ROLEOD;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN
        open output for userResult(i).ROLEOD
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
        open output for userResult(i).ROLEOD
  END;
  END LOOP
;
END;
```

I tried to execute it is giving errors. Can you suggest how I can call the procedure from Sequelize and see the Ids for those update has failed?

Procedure is being called in sequelize like this:

```
let useResultIn=[{"ROLE":"manager","ROLECODE":"ADM","ROLEOD":1},{"ROLE":"admin","ROLECODE":"MNG","ROLEOD":2,}]
      let sequelquery = `BEGIN ROLESUPDATING(:useResultIn,:out);END;`;
          let users = await sequelize.query(sequelquery, {
            bind: {
              useResultIn: {type:"ROLE_ARRAY",val:useResultIn},
              out :{dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type:oracledb.CURSOR}
            }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
          })
          var userIds = [];
          let row;
          while ((row = await users[0].getRow())) {
            userIds.push(row)
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a REF CURSOR for that... try a simple collection type:

```
CREATE TYPE roleod_list as TABLE OF integer;

create or replace PROCEDURE  ROLESUPDATING(useResultIn IN ROLE_ARRAY,Output OUT roleod_list)
IS
  tab_bad_ids roleod_list := roleod_list();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. useResultIn.count
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UPDATE AUTHUSERS SET FIRSTNAME = useResultIn(i).role  where USERID = useResultIn(i).ROLEOD;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        tab_bad_ids.EXTEND;
        tab_bad_ids(tab_bad_ids.LAST) := useResultIn(i).ROLEOD;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  
  Output := tab_bad_ids;
END;
```

The calling program can then receive that and loop through it for any reason:

```
declare
  my_errors roleod_list;
begin
  ROLESUPDATING(useResultIn,my_errors);
  FOR i IN my_errors.FIRST ..my_errors.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(my_errors(i));
  END LOOP;
end;
```